# playing sounds on simultaneous button presses

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio

In my `Launchpad Simulator` there are a lot of Buttons on the main activity. 
I want to play sound on each button press. If the buttons are pressed simultaneously, I want to play the sound simultaneously. From what I made uptil now, it seems that Whenever I press buttons it does play the sound, but since the first sound is 3 seconds long (eg. a clap sound file is 3 seconds long in its playtime).

Before any other sound is produced through buttons, it waits 3 seconds and the plays the next sound if any button is pressed after 3 seconds and same with other 32 buttons.

Just like a launchpad as soon as I press buttons I want a sound to be played. In this case the clap sound.

Here is the Java Code:

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.oniichansblog.launchpadify;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer clap1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        clap1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap1);
    }

    public void clap1(View v){
        clap1.start();
    }

}
```

I only have this one function `clap1()` that is being called over and over everytime I press a button.

[image]

if you want to check it for yourself I have a repository:
[GitHub Repository for LaunchPadify](https://github.com/OniiChanStudio/LaunchPadify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to not define the MediaPlayer above.
Just create a new temporary MediaPlayer every ButtonClick

```
new MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap).start();
```

and it will play sounds simultaneously

**UPDATE**

If you want to destroy a MediaPlayer after it finishes playing the sound, you can do this by using this code

```
new MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.test)
            .start()
            .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Yes that worked quite well but after a few hits on the buttons, it stops clapping. I will leave a link to the app. If you could see for yourself how that it stops making sounds after around hitting for 10-15 times. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5whGfbIoM7KVE56clVXY2dSUFU

Comment: Yeah this is caused by an overflow of Media Player objects. You need to add a onCompletionListener and then release (destroy) a MediaPlayer after the sound finished playing.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. I am new to sound

Answer (score 0):

To play several tracks simultaneously you should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and execute it on THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.
How to do this:
**Thread class**:

```
class PlayThread extends AsyncTask<MediaPlayer, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(MediaPlayer... player) {

        player[0].start();          
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Media Players**:

```
MediaPlayer[] players = new MediaPlayer[5];
//Then set source to each player...
//...
//Create objects of Thread class
PlayThread[] playThreads = new PlayThread[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    playThreads[i] = new PlayThread();
//Set Media Players there and start play
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    playThreads[i].executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, players[i]);
```

---

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) can execute only 5 Threads simultaneously, other are going to queue.

---

[SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) buffer limit is 1Mb, so it is not a solution at all.

---

**It is very important:**
To play simultaneously more audio tracks you should mix them into 1 buffer.
The way to do this: decode mp3 to pcm (to small buffers in stream mode), mix it into one byte buffer and put it to [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) for playing.

Comment: Actually, I have a few questions: What does this line mean `doInBackground(MediaPlayer... player)` , And I don't understand why are there three dots ?. Next you say to add some source to the players. I can set the source. But in the next part you say set Mediaplayer and start play. To be honest, I am new to the Sound and threads. So if you can clarify your code more like as a one on one tutorial that I can maybe use as an example and edit it to my own needs. Also I did not understand the **It is very important part**